# WPF treeview add to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, treeview

I am doing a small WPF project which needs to add the treeview node to listbox, currently i have binding data to my treeview:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}" AllowDrop="True"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Product}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModelName}" AllowDrop="True"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TreeView x:Name="tv_Project" Margin="5" />
```

And i binding the itemsource when initialize the mainwindow:

```
tv_Project.ItemsSource = App.StoreDb.GetCategoriesAndProducts();
```

But i don't know how to write the code to add the treevide node to listbox,usually an application goes lick: right_click the treeview node to add it to listbox(or directly drag the treeview node to listbox), hope i explain my issues clearly, thanks!

Comment: Do you have different ListBoxes for Category and Product, or are you using same ?

Comment: Just One Listbox

Comment: You can have a ListBox that can show the list of strings. These strings can be the name of category and model. Now, add a context menu on tree view nodes. On right-click, the context menu will open and you can add category or model to listBox. On click of the context menu, add selected item to Listbox items source.